# How Do I Pull a Single Commit In Git?

Tags: git, github, hash, tree, branch

Someone fixed an error in a program on Github, but it hasn't been added to the master branch. I want to just pull this one commit, but everything I've tried gives an error saying bad object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would be easier to:

- `git fetch` (the brings everything locally)
- `git cherry-pick <SHA1 of the right commit>`

Once the fetch is done, you can [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commit which fixes the error (it should be part of `git log origin/xxx`, with `xxx` being the branch where the bug fix was committed on the GitHub side)

Once the bug fix locally cherry-picked in the local `master` branch, a simple git push will publish that new commit on the GitHub `master` branch.

---

If the commit is from another fork:

```
git remote add otherfork /url/to/other/fork
git fetch otherfork
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

Comment: Running cherry-pick with the hash gives `fatal: bad object 67be47b408d15d433d85044dca7d21f1cbfdae0a`

Comment: @Kookerus did you do a `git fetch` first?

Comment: I did. I cloned the repo, ran `git fetch`, and then `git cherry-pick 67be47b408d15d433d85044dca7d21f1cbfdae0a`

Comment: @Kookerus is that SHA1 visible in the GitHub repo whose url matches '`origin`' when doing a `git remote -v`?

Comment: @Kookerus Or is `67be47b408d15d433d85044dca7d21f1cbfdae0a` visible in *another* repo (like a fork)?

Comment: It is, and it's got the fix I need.

Comment: @Kookerus As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13789405/6309, try a `git fetch --all` first.

Comment: @Kookerus or, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27145793/6309, check if the commit is in the same repo (or in a submodule)

Comment: I'm still getting `Fatal: bad object`

Comment: @Kookerus It should be simple: if you can see that commit in a `gitk --all`, as in http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/04/pick-out-individual-commits.html, you should be able to cherry-pick it without any issue (provided you are on the master branch: `git checkout master` first)

Comment: I feel like a complete moron. The commit was from another fork, and because I still don't understand github very well, I thought it was from the original repo.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Kookerus No problem. I have edited the answer to reflect the actual solution.

Comment: Thanks, I never even thought of just adding the other fork.