# How to copy files with their history among different git repositories?

Tags: git, merge, repository

I have files of a project A which have been copied into project B. In a branch of B, the code originally belonging to project A has been modified.

How can I copy the history of changes done in B's branch into the original project A?

Consider that I do not want to copy all the files of project B into A, but just the ones which already belong to project A.

Reference: [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788945/how-to-cherry-pick-from-a-remote-branch Cherry-pick the commits?

Answer (score 2):

(I put part of this in as a comment, but decided to expand on it.)

Note that in Git, *files* do not have history.  Commits *are* history, and commits have files.

For instance, perhaps commit `a666666` has files `A`, `B`, and `C` and message "modify A", and its history is "parent is `a555555`".  Now we step back to commit `a555555`.  It has files `A`, `B`, and `C` and message "add file C" and parent `a444444`.  We then step back to commit `a444444`, which has files `A` and `B`, parent `a333333`, and some message; and so on.

It sounds like what you want to do is extract every commit that touches certain paths ("files in project B"), copy those specific file-paths over to some other repository, and then—in that other repository—make a new commit, perhaps re-using the commit message from the current commit.

There are a number of ways to do this.  None is necessarily best, although some may make things easier, depending on just what results you want.  None are completely built-in to Git either, so you must do at least a little bit of programming.  I'll show one method, which is the most obvious to me.

You should also decide what, if anything, you want to do with merge commits.  Merges cause non-linear history, and copying non-linear history requires either extreme cleverness, or some sort of simplification.  I will leave details to you.

As for how to copy the commits, here are two relatively simplistic methods that assume we only care about some sort linear or linearize-able history.

#### Basic setup and finding interesting commits

Set up repo *src*, the source repository that contains commits you want to make copies from (i.e., a repo copy of project B in your question).  Set up second repo *dst*, the destination (target) into which you will copy files from commit in *src*.

Now we need to find "interesting commits".  These are commits that modify "interesting files", i.e., files that you wish to copy into *dst*.

The Git command to list commit IDs is `git rev-list`, which takes about four billion options to specify which Git objects are interesting and how to show them.  In our case we want commits, listed in reverse topological order (oldest first), starting from the latest point you want to copy from—probably a branch name—and probably stopping at some specified point, but only those commits that modified specific path(s).  Hence:

```
git rev-list --topo-order --reverse latest ^stopat -- path1 path2 ... pathN
```

(Note that you may list directory paths.)  Here `latest` is the branch name, or a commit ID; `^stopat` is the literal character `^` followed by a name or another commit ID; and the `path`s are the names of all the files, or directories full of files, that are "interesting".

You may want to include `--first-parent` and/or `--no-merges` as well, depending on how you want your history linearized.  Study [the `git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) to decide for yourself.

(Along the way, you may note that `stopat..latest` is a shorthand syntax for the same thing we did in longer form above.)

You may want to redirect the output of the above command to a file, since it might be quite long.  You can then inspect the selected revisions, or some random subset of them, to see if you like the ones selected.  (Use `git show` to view specific commits; note that by default, `git show` uses combined diffs to show merge commits.)

Now that you have a list of interesting commits, we can go on to the methods for copying (part of) those commits from *src* to *dst*.  Note: none of the code below is tested.

#### Method: literal copy

This is probably the simplest method.  Write a script that iterates through each commit ID and checks out that commit in *src*, then copies the files from *src* to *dst*, `git add`s them in *dst*, and runs `git commit`.  It's OK to re-`add` files that are not changed, so this script is pretty simple.  This assumes that `./list-of-files` contains "interesting" paths and the repos are in `./src` and `./dst`, with the interesting commit revision IDs in `./interesting`.  (You must write `die`; it's a simple shell function.)  It probably has some issues if not every path exists in every commit (not a problem if the paths are just one subdirectory).  It definitely has issues if any of the `path` arguments have whitespace in them, since `$(cat ../list-of-paths)` will just split at any white space.

```
while read rev; do
    (cd src &&
     git checkout -q $rev &&
     git log -1 --pretty=format:%B > ../commit-msg) ||
    die "failed to check out $rev in src"

    (cd src && cp -R $(cat ../list-of-paths) ../dst/) ||
    die "failed to copy files from src to dst"

    (cd dst &&
     git add -- $(cat ../list-of-paths) &&
     git commit -q -F ../commit-msg) ||
    die "failed to commit $rev in dst"
done < interesting
```

Answer (score 1):

See 'git help git' for  GIT_DIR  environment variable.  Then add the Project B modified files, as if you were in Project B directory.  Something like the following example.

move to project B and set git to Project A, Verify the Project A git with the 'rev-parse' command

```
cd <ProjectB>
GIT_DIR="<ProjectA/.git>"
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

get list of modified files, enter the changed files manually from results of 'git status'

```
git diff --name-status --diff-filter=M
files="<changedFile1> <changedFile2> <...>"
```

put files changed in Project B to Project A's Repository

```
git add -- $files
git commit -m"commit files modified in Project B"
```

Restore git repository

```
GIT_DIR=
```

Comment: After:  `cd "path_to_B" ; GIT_DIR="path_to_A/.git" ; git rev-parse --git-dir` I get this: `path_to_B/.git` . Is it Ok? In A repository nothing changed, I still have the old version.

Comment: It should say path_to_A.git, if not then reassigning the git repository did not work.   If you are windows type  'set GIT_DIR=<projectA\.git>  and at the end 'set GIT_DIR='.  and then confirm with the git rev-parse.  see also 'git help git' for the --git-dir command line option.