# Git cherry-picking remote commit from upstream, in a branch that isn't master

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have the following situation which is different than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788945/how-to-cherry-pick-from-a-remote-branch).

Here's my local repo:

```
$ git branch
  branch1
  ...
  branchk
  master
* this-branch-where-fix-should-happen
```

What I want is to apply a commit that only exists in the `upstream:staging` branch.

I've tried to fetch upstream in a certain branch

```
$ git fetch upstream staging:staging

From github.com:<org>/<repo>
 * [new branch]              staging    -> staging
```

New output from `branch`.

```
$ git branch
  branch1
  ...
  branchk
  master
  staging
* this-branch-where-fix-should-happen
```

Now trying to cherry pick into `fix-branch`:

```
$ git cherry-pick -x <sha-1>
    fatal: bad object <sha-1>
```

Is there a correct way to cherry pick in this situation? Or am I doing it the completely wrong way?

---

## Solution: Finding the problem and fixing it

As instructed by Tim Biegeleisen

Fetching upstream

```
$ git fetch upstream
```

This is where my mistake was, I was getting the commit number via the github site, however that was actually a `<sha-1>` for the merge. To get the correct commit number:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --grep="<some-info-about-the-commit>" upstream/staging
```

I've used `--grep="#pull-request-number"` and got the correct commit id.

```
<correct-sha-1> PR description (#PR-number)
```

Now trying to cherry pick into `fix-branch`:

```
$ git cherry-pick -x <correct-sha-1>
```

And it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you `git fetch`, the `staging` remote branch should actually exist *locally*, as a *tracking* branch called `upstream/staging`, or something similar to that.  If you want to target a specific commit from this tracking branch, which mirrors the remote, just type

```
git log upstream/staging
```

to see the commits from this branch, and pick the one you want.  Now cherry picking should work:

```
# from the this-branch-where-fix-should-happen branch
git cherry-pick -x <sha-1 from staging>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've edited the question and accept this answer.