# Cherry pick failed for commit a0946a562a8e

Tags: git, patch, pull-request

I'm trying to test a change that is queued as a pull request. The pull request is on GitHub and located [here](https://github.com/p11-glue/p11-kit/pull/252). My script is:

```
export P11KIT_DIR=p11-kit-master

rm -rf "$P11KIT_DIR" 2>/dev/null

if ! git clone --depth=3 https://github.com/p11-glue/p11-kit.git "$P11KIT_DIR";
then
    echo "Failed to checkout p11-kit"
    exit 1
fi

cd "$P11KIT_DIR"

if ! git cherry-pick a0946a562a8e;
then
    echo "Failed to patch p11-kit"
    exit 1
fi
```

The script is dying with the error:

```
fatal: bad revision 'a0946a562a8e'
Failed to patch p11-kit
```

[a0946a562a8e](https://github.com/p11-glue/p11-kit/pull/252/commits/a0946a562a8e) is clearly the revision number. I took it directly from GitHub. I'm guessing `cherry-pick` is the wrong command.

How do I add a0946a562a8e into master?

Comment: That commit isn't in `p11-glue/p11-kit`, it's in `ueno/p11-kit`. Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/13788945/3001761.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You’re looking for the commit in the wrong repository
- `--depth` implies `--single-branch`, so if it were the right repository you still wouldn’t be getting the right branch

GitHub [provides refs for pull requests](https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally), though, so you can do this, replacing the `cherry-pick` step:

```sh
if ! git fetch origin pull/252/head;
then
    echo "Failed to fetch pull request"
    exit 1
fi

if ! git merge FETCH_HEAD;
then
    echo "Failed to patch p11-kit"
    exit 1
fi
```